# How can you display with MongoDB error in MeteorJs?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm getting a strange error in Meteor. It allows me to update a count, but when I try to reverse the count, it won't update.

```
Template.listItem.events({
'click .remove': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ListItems.remove(this._id);
    //Router.go('listPage', {_id: template.data._id});
},
'click .listItem': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = ListItems.findOne(this._id);
    ListItems.update(this._id, {$set: { picked: true }});
    Items.update(item.itemId, {$inc: {pickedCount: 1}});
},
'click .picked': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = ListItems.findOne(this._id);
    console.log(item.itemId);
    ListItems.update(this._id, {$set: { picked: false }});
    Items.update({_id: item.itemId}, {$inc: {pickedCount: -1}});
}
});
```

The pickedCount is what I'm trying to revert. Everything I've read said this should work. How can I display the error from MongoDB if there is one? Is this the accepted syntax for decrementing a field in Mongo?

Comment: Can you paste the _strange error_ you are seeing here? It will help in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most `Meteor.call` functions (or which `Collection.update` is one), take a last argument as a callback. From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#update):

> *callback Function* Optional. If present, called with an error object as
>   the first argument and, if no error, the number of affected documents
>   as the second.

Hence, you can write your call to `update` as:

```
Items.update({_id: item.itemId}, {$inc: {pickedCount: -1}}, function (err) {
    console.log("Error = ", err);
});
```

However, the error on the server console is likely to be more informative in your case.

Comment: This error responded with "Error =  undefined". When I watch an item that displays pickedCount, the count will increase whenever I click an item that hasn't been picked. If I click an item to revert it to not being picked, it does not decrement the item pickCount.